# case when in where clause postresql

Tags: postgresql

```sql
select service_code,service_cat_code,mobile_no,upper(applicant_name_eng) as name,to_char(license_date,'dd/mm/yyyy')as license_from,to_char(license_valid_upto,'dd/mm/yyyy')as license_to,Upper(license_no),district_code,taluk_code,CONCAT(address_building,', ', address_cityvillage,', ',address_locality,', ',address_landmark,', ',address_street) as address 
from mst_license    
WHERE cast(license_valid_upto as date)   =   case 
                                  WHEN  license_valid_upto < now()
                                       THEN 
                                            case 
                                                when license_valid_upto = '2021-06-30'
                                                    then 1 else 0
                                            END
                                  ELSE 
                                      case when license_valid_upto > now() 
                                                then 1 else 0
                                      End
                              END  
                              and Upper(license_no)='1SP146924BJP'
```

I want license valid should be either greater than now or if license valid less than now it must be with the date ''30/06/2021' but when i use above query i get error

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: date = integer
LINE 3: WHERE cast(license_valid_upto as date)   =   case 
                                                 ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 418
```

Help me out guys

Comment: `when license_valid_upto = '2021-06-30'::date` will probably fix it.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't worked

Comment: This would be much easier to implement, and to understand when you come back to it a year from now, as a function with variables rather than as a query with multiply embedded **CASE**s. Is there a reason you can't do that?

Comment: I've just started sql'ing for a while, I know it can be done in easier way and by using functions, let me find another way or search through online researches

Answer (score 0):

The main issue you have is that your case statement returns an integer (1 or 0) but you are trying to compare that to a date, which you cannot do as Postgres is a strict data typing. Even if it did work it would always be false (well except for 1969-12-31/1970-01-01). Moreover the case structure is not needed. The best/correct to compare dates is just use date values. Since you did not indicate the data type for column *license_valid_upto* so based on how it is used I'll assume it is *timestamp with timezone* as that is what NOW() returns. Your query becomes:

```
select service_code
     , service_cat_code
     , mobile_no
     , upper(applicant_name_eng) as name
     , to_char(license_date,'dd/mm/yyyy')as license_from
     , to_char(license_valid_upto,'dd/mm/yyyy')as license_to
     , upper(license_no) as license_no
     , district_code
     , taluk_code
     , concat(address_building,', '
             ,address_cityvillage,', '
             ,address_locality,', '
             ,address_landmark,', '
             ,address_street) as address 
from mst_license    
where and upper(license_no)='1SP146924BJP'
  and (   cast(license_valid_upto as date) > cast( now() as date) 
       or (cast (icense_valid_upto as date) <  cast( now() as date) 
            and cast (icense_valid_upto as date) = date '2021-06-30'
          )
      );
```

Also, learn for format your queries for readability and so you do not need to scroll right. You, and others looking at your queries later will appreciate it later.